# reduce surface integral to line integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the following integral
$$
\int_{ABC}{\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla f_id\sigma}
$$
where $d\sigma$ is an area element, $\mathbf v$ is a velocity vector and $f_i$ some function. The integral is performed across a triangle ABC.

In my book this integral becomes
$$
\mathbf v\cdot \int_{AB}{f_id\mathbf l} + I_s,
$$
where $I_s$ is the flux across $BC$ and $AC$. Can someone explain to me how this integral is solved? They mention that it is assumed $f$ is **linear**.

It seems like some Gauss theorem in 2D (?).

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a stocke's theorem problem. Recall stocke's theorem defines the equivalence between surface integral and line integral

Comment: "Stokes'" ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Since it's in the plane (apparently) I would say Green's theorem, though of course it's corollary of Stokes.

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific?